# Comparing and contrasting classification trees over the years

Tags: cart, inference

At work I have decided to use a classification tree to do some analysis on the people at the bottom decile for hourly pay. Mainly for inferential reasons.

My datasets are broken up in years, I have 2013, 2012, ... , 2006. I just wanted to know if I can build trees for each of those years, and then compare and contrast them? So in one year the total hours worked variable may be in there as one of the nodes, and in another year it may not be, can I conclude that in the year that it was, it was a more important factor in the person being in the bottom decile?

I'm using the same methodology for them all, i.e the datasets for each year are set up the same way with the same variables, no missing values, cross-validating to get the best cp value, and then building the tree.

Thanks in advance.

Rafi